# How to add different destination dynamically to JMSListener Annotation in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, spring-annotations

I working on an application which reads message from Azure service bus. This application was created using spring boot, Spring jms and Qpid jms client. I am able to read the message properly from Queue without any issues. PFB My code which I am using to read message.

```
@Service
public class QueueReceiver {
@JmsListener(destination = "testing")
public void onMessage(String message) {
    if (null != message) {
        System.out.println("Received message from Queue: " + message);
    }
}}
```

Issue is we have different destinations for different environemnts, like `testing` for `dev`, `testing-qa` for `qa` and `testing-prod` for `production`, all these values are provided as `azure.queueName` in different application-(ENV).proerpties respectively. I want to pass these destinations dynamically to the destination in JmsListener Annotation. When i try using

```
@Value("${azure.queueName}")
private String dest;
```

and passing dest to annotation like `@JmsListener(destination = dest)`

I am getting `The value for annotation attribute JmsListener.destination must be a constant expression` Error. After googling with this Error i found that we cannot pass dynamic value to Annotation. Please help me how to resolve this issue or any other solution for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
destination="${azure.queueName}"
```

i.e. put the placeholder in the annotation directly.

Comment: Does it support Spring Cloud Configuration? If the property is provided by the configuration server, it seems that after calling Actuator refresh endpoint the destination is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic name as defined in the application.properties file.For Example:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name}")
```

Since you can't access any class variables here so this is the best option available.